# jQuery validation when pages are loaded through ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading pages via jQuery load function.
My problem is jQuery validation works fine for first page but as other pages are loaded via ajax it does not work.  Please find jsp & js file below.
    Is it because page source code doesn't changes when using ajax page load.
    Should i use show/hide function?
        //Main.jsp

```
              <script
                src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"
                type="text/javascript"></script>

            <script
                src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js"
                type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script
                src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
                type="text/javascript"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet"
                href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

            <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/styles.css' />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="Jquery/myscript.js"></script>


            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="top">
                    <div id='mainMenu'>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='#'><span>Hot Deals</span></a></li>
                            <li><a><span id="logPage">Login</span></a></li>
                            <li><a id="regPage"><span>Register</span></a></li>
                            <li><a id="usPage"><span>About</span></a></li>
                            <li class="last"><a id="adminPage"><span>Adminstration</span></a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="mainPages">
                        <jsp:include page="Search.jsp"></jsp:include>
                    </div>
                    <div id="errors">
                        <s:actionerror />
                        <s:actionmessage />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </body>
            </html>
        //main.js

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#logPage").click(function() {

                $('#mainPages').empty();
                $('#mainPages').load('Index.jsp');
            });
            $("#regPage").click(function() {

                $('#mainPages').empty();
                $('#mainPages').load("Register.jsp");
            });
            $("#usPage").click(function() {

                $('#mainPages').empty();
                $('#mainPages').load("About.html");
            });
            $("#home").click(function() {

                $('#mainPages').empty();
                $('#mainPages').load("Search.jsp");
            });
            $("#adminPage").click(function() {

                $('#mainPages').empty();
                $('#mainPages').load("../AdminLogin.jsp");
            });

        });
    //myscript.js
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#myform").validate({
            rules : {
                email : {
                    required : true,
                    email : true
                },
                password : {
                    required : true,
                    minlength : 8
                },

            },
            messages : {
                email : {
                    required : "Please Enter email",
                    email : "Valid Email Please"
                }
            }
        });

        $("#regform").validate({

            rules : {
                email : {
                    required : true,
                    email : true
                },
                password : {
                    required : true,
                    minlength : 8
                },
                fname : {
                    required : true,
                    lettersonly : true
                },
                lname : {
                    lettersonly : true
                },
                mname : {
                    lettersonly : true
                },
                geneder : {
                    required : true
                },
                city : {
                    required : true
                },
                zip : {
                    required : true,
                    digits : true,
                    minlength : 6,
                    maxlength : 6
                },
                mobno : {
                    required : true,
                    digits : true,
                    minlength : 10,
                    maxlength : 10
                },
                dob : {
                    required : true
                }
            },
            messages : {
                email : {
                    required : "Please Enter email",
                    email : "Valid Email Please"
                }
            }

        });
        $("#travelDate").datepicker({
            defaultDate : '0',
            numberOfMonths : 1,
            minDate : '0',
            maxDate : '1M'
        });
        $("#searchForm").validate({

            rules : {
                fromCity : {
                    required : true,
                    lettersonly : true,

                },
                toCity : {
                    required : true,
                    lettersonly : true
                },
                seats : {
                    required : true,
                    digits : true,
                    min : 1,
                    max : 9,
                },
                travelDate : {
                    required : true,
                }
            },
            messages : {

            }
        });
    });
    )};
```

Comment: Attach validation after every ajax request

Comment: all pages contain myscript.js?

Comment: @Sridhar R yes all pages contain myscript.js

Comment: @Ahmad can you provide some link/reference for attaching validation after every ajax request?

Comment: ur ajax response pages have validation script?

Comment: @bawanaBoy wrap all of your validation code in a function, then you call the function after load is completed example  `$('#mainPages').load('Index.jsp', validateFunc() );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `main.js` is fine...

try these steps:

1) Change the `$(document).ready(function()` to the method lets call `function validator()` in `myscript.js`
.

2) use `onload=validator()` in all the pages you are loading by ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for your input
I didn't wanted to validate on load rather on submit/onclick of form.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(){
   var $form = $(this).closest('form');
       $form.validate({
```

repeat above for all `form`

Comment: thanks
I have many forms on same page how will i distinguish b/w them.

Answer (score 0):

Existence of elements which are loaded dynamically needs to be determined by `$("#someDynamicElement").live()` instead of `$(document).ready()`.. Try if this helps you, I had a similar problem when I was generating forms..